# Reasons for Permission denied on execution

Tags: linux, centos

I have a binary executable that I am able to run on my CentOS7 machine. I `scp` it to another CentOS7 machine and get Permission denied when trying to run it. I am using the root user, the file is owned by root and I have enabled all permissions (and same with the directory where I put it):

```
# ls -lisa notserv 
5112112 35292 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36136938 Sep 14 08:23 notserv
# ls -lisad .
5112110 4 drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Sep 14 08:23 .
# ./notserv 
-bash: ./notserv: Permission denied
```

SELinux is not enabled:

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

This other machine is maintained by a different team in the company and probably has a different configuration. My question is: what other reasons could there be for this outcome?

**EDIT**

I am using partition `/tmp` which does not seem to have the `noexec` flag set:

```
# pwd
/tmp
# mount | grep /tmp
/dev/md126p8 on /tmp type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered)
```

**EDIT2**

Some more info about the file and the OS:

```
# file notserv 
notserv: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, BuildID[sha1]=7d5c9389a3c67ff50f9a16be3e47efd32f57e2c7, not stripped

# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

# uname -a
Linux oms0 3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 30 14:19:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As for ldd:

```
# ldd notserv 
     not a dynamic executable
```

BUT, on the original machine it says:

```
# ldd notserv 
     linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf772f000)
     libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf76fd000)
     libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76e2000)
     libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf75f6000)
     libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf75b4000)
     libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7598000)
     libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf73cd000)
     /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7730000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system, but your system does not have the 32-bit C library (glibc) or any other 32-bit libraries installed.

You can install the necessary 32-bit compatibility libraries:

```
yum install glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686
```

Now you should be able to run the program.

---

Alternately, you can try to obtain a 64-bit binary from the source who provided this binary to you.

Comment: Hi @Michael. You are completely right. I totally forgot about compatibility libraries. Indeed the second machine did not have them, but since the OS's are the same, I was able to copy them over from the first machine (where the executable was running) and now it's running there also. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @VladNicola If possible you should install them via `yum` instead, so that you can get security and critical updates for them.

Answer (score 1):

It could be you are in a directory mounted with the `noexec` option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on arm64 embedded system with own initramfs the error fully fixed by 2 simple commands:

```
# chmod a+x /lib/ld-2.31.so
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib"
```

How I've found this fix? Really I had not any ideas how to fix. On host system command like:

```
$ ~/x-tools/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-ldd --root . <path to dynamically linked executable>
```

was shown that all libraries are there on initramfs image.
And then I searched how to run "ldd" on embedded system and did:

```
$ file <..>/sysroot/usr/bin/ldd
<..>/sysroot/usr/bin/ldd: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Wow, ldd is BASH script, really??? I couldn't to believe and made:

```
$ file /bin/ldd
/bin/ldd: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

So I've seen this script and found other surprise:

```
$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --help
Usage: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [OPTION]... EXECUTABLE-FILE [ARGS-FOR-PROGRAM...]
You have invoked 'ld.so', the program interpreter for dynamically-linked
ELF programs.  Usually, the program interpreter is invoked automatically
when a dynamically-linked executable is started.

You may invoke the program interpreter program directly from the command
line to load and run an ELF executable file; this is like executing that
file itself, but always uses the program interpreter you invoked,
instead of the program interpreter specified in the executable file you
run.  Invoking the program interpreter directly provides access to
additional diagnostics, and changing the dynamic linker behavior without
setting environment variables (which would be inherited by subprocesses).

  --list                list all dependencies and how they are resolved
  --verify              verify that given object really is a dynamically linked
                        object we can handle
  --inhibit-cache       Do not use /etc/ld.so.cache
  --library-path PATH   use given PATH instead of content of the environment
                        variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  --glibc-hwcaps-prepend LIST
                        search glibc-hwcaps subdirectories in LIST
  --glibc-hwcaps-mask LIST
                        only search built-in subdirectories if in LIST
  --inhibit-rpath LIST  ignore RUNPATH and RPATH information in object names
                        in LIST
  --audit LIST          use objects named in LIST as auditors
  --preload LIST        preload objects named in LIST
  --argv0 STRING        set argv[0] to STRING before running
  --list-tunables       list all tunables with minimum and maximum values
  --list-diagnostics    list diagnostics information
  --help                display this help and exit
  --version             output version information and exit

This program interpreter self-identifies as: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Shared library search path:
  (libraries located via /etc/ld.so.cache)
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (system search path)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (system search path)
  /lib (system search path)
  /usr/lib (system search path)

Subdirectories of glibc-hwcaps directories, in priority order:
  x86-64-v4
  x86-64-v3 (supported, searched)
  x86-64-v2 (supported, searched)

Legacy HWCAP subdirectories under library search path directories:
  haswell (AT_PLATFORM; supported, searched)
  tls (supported, searched)
  avx512_1
  x86_64 (supported, searched)
```

So ld-library is not simple library, it is "interpreter" and must have executable right. You can easy use ld.so with "--list" argument instead of ldd like this:

```
$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff2b147000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f023b940000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f023b75f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f023bac5000)
```

And `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib"` is necessary to know path to look up libraries.